# import one image and one text file -- display the text file contents when image is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload one image and its corresponding text file. text file contain image's attributes.
How can I display the contents of text file when the image is selected using checkbox.

One more thing: when I upload only text file the contents are clear in English but when I upload image and text file the content of text files are in some other font( not readable) and I want to display the contents only when image is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnf0bht7/11/

```
    function fileUpload(inputFile,preview){
    var file =inputFile;
    var imageType = /^image\//; 
    var fileTemp = null;

    var container = $("<div class='ct'><input  value='remove'type='checkbox'/></div>");
    if (imageType.test(file.type)) { 
        fileTemp = document.createElement("img"); 
        fileTemp.classList.add("preview_image");      

    fileTemp.file = file;
    container.append(fileTemp);
    $("#iso_preview").append(container);
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; 
    })(fileTemp);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        } else{
       onFileSelected(event);
    }
}

function onFileSelected(event) {
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle text and image files differently. I suggest you to modify your program from the line containing `var reader = new FileReader();` (and below) like this:

```
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    if (imageType.test(file.type)) {
        reader.onload = function(e) { fileTemp.src = e.target.result; };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        reader.onload = function(e) { $(fileTemp).text(e.target.result); };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6qfryn/

Basically you need to check if the file is an image file or a text file. If it is an image file then the `function` I assign to `reader.onload` is very similar to your existing function, but I changed it to a more readable one liner. It was possible because there is no need to pass the `fileTemp` object to a self-invoking function, because in this case we can simply access the fileTemp object via closure. So instead of this "mess" :

```
reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; 
    })(fileTemp);
```

you can just do this:

```
reader.onload = function(e) { fileTemp.src = e.target.result; };
```

The `fileTemp` variable will be accessible from the callback function thanks to closure.

If the file is not an image file then for simplicity let's assume that it is a text file (it's a bad assumption!) and in that case we can assign this `function` to `reader.onload` :

```
function(e) { $(fileTemp).text(e.target.result); }
```

In this function I used a jQuery wrapper around the `fileTemp` variable to make it a jQuery object and then I used [jQuery's .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to place the file contents into the div.

There is another important difference: We need to read image files with the `reader.readAsDataURL` method, while text files need to be read with the `reader.readAsText`. [I looked up the relevant FileReader API info here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api).

Comment: This looks good but I want to display the text in a separate text data or some separate div and the data is shown when the image is clicked.and at present on the browser there can be many images but only one text which is of the selected image

Comment: @PSDebugger I see. And how do you know which text file belongs to which image file? They share the same name but the file extension is different? Actually, how do you guarantee that every image has a corresponding text file also uploaded?

Comment: yes they share the same name and the extensioin is different. Sorry I forgot to mention. there is only 2 types of files which will be uploaded image and text :)

Comment: I guarantee this because this is how the design is

Comment: @PSDebugger Well, it can be done. But the code would be much more complex because you have two completely separate file upload (or just file selection for upload) events: one for uploading a file and another for uploading the text file. These two events are not tied together at all. You need to tie these two together with your program code, you must use the file.name to find out if the two uploads (an image file and a text file) have the same name and if they do you need to store the data in the DOM in a way which you can easily retrieve the image file's text when someone clicks on an image.

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to find it by using the file.name to identify if the text file belongs to the image or not. And then save the txt file in the dom and display its contents when the image is selected. I am clueless how to proceed in this step.

Comment: can you give me a layout how to proceed from here. how can I store the image and text data in the DOM?